# Which JBoss application server's version is stable and latest?

Tags: jboss

I am new to JBoss application server. when I go for download the application server in the website. I am seeing the below servers list in the top

1. EAP built from AS 7.3.
2. EAP 6.2 Maven Repository.
3. EAP 6.2 Quickstarts.

   kindly help me. Which is the best one. otherwise, shall I go for any other open source application server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to make any comment about these things you mentioned. But I can share my experience with you.

1. Jboss 5.1: It was good.
2. Jboss 7.1: I faced a problem with log4j issue. Its very complicated.
3. EAP 6.2: Its much stable than 7.1. my log4j problem is solved with this version.

So, it totally depends upon how deep you want to use jboss.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am going to develop client-server design to collect the feedback from users.